# Saving images in separate folders

Tags: python, save

I wrote a code that reads nifti volumes from a folder (image_dir).  I want to save axial slices from each volume into separate folders.  When I run the code , all the folders are created in the folder at location provided in `p1`. But all the images are stored outside corresponding folders, that is in the folder `p1`. Please help me correct it.

```
import matplotlib
from scipy import ndimage
#from scipy.ndimage import morphology
import os
import nibabel as nib
from nibabel import processing
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import scipy.ndimage.interpolation
from os.path import join
import cv2 
from PIL import Image

image_dir ='/home/user1/Documents/Segmentation/' 

p1 = '/home/user1/Downloads/T1_Axial/'

image_filenames = sorted(glob.glob(image_dir + '**/*.nii', recursive=True))
         
for img in image_filenames:              
    filename = os.path.basename(img)
    filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]     
    
    path = '{}'.format(filename)
    cp = join(p1, path)
    print(cp)   
    os.mkdir(str(cp)) 
    
    medical_image = nib.load(img)
    image = medical_image.get_fdata()
    img_affine = medical_image.affine      
  
    for i in range(image.shape[2]):      
     
        axial_image=image[:, :, i]
        img1 = nib.Nifti1Image(axial_image, np.eye(4))           
        nib.save(img1,cp + '' + str(i) + '.nii')
```

Comment: For the line `cp + '' + str(i) + '.nii'`, print out that string and see if the path looks correct. It seems like there might be a slash missing between the folder and file name, in which case the files would just go in the parent folder with the folder name appended to their filename.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. It is working after putting slash as you suggested.